# Time getting function implementation

Tags: c++, visual-studio

This is the implementation of the official `Quake 2` time retrieving function used later in the main *game loop*:

```
int curtime;
int Sys_Milliseconds (void)
{
    static int      base;
    static qboolean initialized = false;

    if (!initialized)
    {   // let base retain 16 bits of effectively random data
        base = timeGetTime() & 0xffff0000;
        initialized = true;
    }
    curtime = timeGetTime() - base;

    return curtime;
}
```

My question is what's for the

```
if (!initialized)
    {   // let base retain 16 bits of effectively random data
        base = timeGetTime() & 0xffff0000;
        initialized = true;
    }
```

section?

Why do they subtract the `base` to get the current time, why just not call `timeGetTime` directly (without all the `base` stuff)?

Comment: I can only guess: A problem with ``timeGetTime()`` is that the returned time will wrap around after 2^32 milliseconds. They might try to prevent this. (But they should have used an unsigned 32bit integer, I think)

Comment: @Christian Halaszovich "They might try to prevent this." - sorry but i don't get it. How can they prevent that wrap around if the effective `curtime` wraps WAY more often  since it's vale oscillates between 0000x-FFFFx instead of 00000000x-FFFFFFFFx due to the subtraction!?

Comment: The subtraction does not mage it wrap more often. Why should the result be restricted to 0x0000 - 0xFFFF? That would be the case of you do ``curtime&0xffff``.
A wrap-around will occur for ``timeGetTime()`` and also for ``Sys_Milliseconds()`` every 49.7 days. But for ``timeGetTime()`` this is counting from system startup, for ``Sys_Milliseconds()``  from  time of initialization of ``base``, which probably happens quite soon after the start of the program (so it is unlikely we reach the warp-around).

Comment: @ChristianHalaszovich Sorry friend but I still don't understand it. Can You please explain me once more what do You mean by "wrap around", give an example please...

Comment: @ChristianHalaszovich I'm I right that to deal with the _wrap around_ problem we we don't have to use **timeGetTime** in the **base** variable initialization, we could as well have used some random number generation function like standard **rand** because the point is to subtract some random, unique value from actually retrieved current time just not to get the zero value in case of the wrap around?

Comment: @ChristianHalaszovich Sorry friend but I still don't fully understand it. Can You please explain me HOW does subtracting the `base` from `timeGetTime` result CAN prevent that wrap around? Can You please give me an example? Thx.

Comment: It can't prevent the wrap around, but it may occur at a later time.
But now I think the main reason for what they do is that they want that the first time the function ``Sys_Milliseconds`` is called it does not return 0, but a kind-of-random value.
But that is all speculation.

Comment: @ChristianHalaszovich "they want that the first time the function Sys_Milliseconds is called it does not return 0" - why do they want that?